# Doxygen and package.html

Tags: package, javadoc, doxygen

As per javadoc specifications, I placed a documentation file called package-info.html in the root directory of the relevant package. When I run Doxygen on that folder, however, the documentation in this file is not picked up. How do I tell Doxygen to use this file as the package documentation? I also tried package.html, the old specification, but that doesn't work., either

Comment: Actually, the current practice is to use a `package-info.java` instead of `package.html`. (No idea about Doxygen, though.)

Comment: Alright, I changed it and doxygen still doesn't do it right. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Just to make sure: It is `package-info.java`, not `.html`, and [it has a different syntax](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment).

Comment: That worked! Apparently javadoc still works with the old way, but Doxygen only works with the new way. Post as an answer and I'll accept you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new alternative way to provide documentation for a Java package is to use a file named `package-info.java` instead of `package.html`. (The file name is intentionally chosen not to be a valid class name.)

It has a different syntax:

```
/**
 * any javadoc comments (including tags)
 */
package name;
```

This is also the only way to provide package annotations (which are noted before the `package` keyword here, if any).

From your comments to the question, it looks like recent versions of Doxygen only understand this `package-info.java`, not the old `package.html` file.

I recall there being a module system proposed, which then would add a similar `module-info.java` file, but I don't find it now after a short googleing. (Maybe JSR 294?)